# Improving performance by loading URI after activity is created

Tags: android, uri, oncreate

I've got an app with an activity that may or may not load a streaming MP3. I'm using the wonderful [AudioWife](https://github.com/jaydeepw/audio-wife) library to do so. However, this causes a really significant delay when the activity is opened. This is extremely annoying on slower devices or connections (the screen sometimes even turns black for seconds). The delay does not occur when there's no streaming mp3. The delay isn't caused specifically by AudioWife, since the code I used before caused the same delay.

The problem is obviously that I'm loading an URI `onCreate()`, so the activity waits until it retrieved the meta information such as length.

Here's the part of my `onCreate()`

```
if (showMusic){
    LinearLayout musicContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MusicContainer);
    musicContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mixLink);
    AudioWife.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), uri)
    .useDefaultUi(musicContainer , getLayoutInflater());
    [...]
}
```

I'd like the heavy lifting (the loading of the mp3) to start after the activity is created, to prevent the activity from freezing.

I've tried putting the code above into an ASyncTask, to no avail, since the line that causes the problem (`init()`) needs to be run on the graphical thread. If I put the part of the code in `doInBackground()` the app crashes. If I put that part of the code into `onPostExecute()` the app doesn't crash, but the delay is still there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well if that `init()` method needs to be run on the UI thread I dont see what you can do besides not using that library. you can always use a handler to delay that code for a second or 2 but thats still going to have the delay

Comment: @tyczj I might have been too early with that. The stacktrace doesn't necessarily say that. Here's the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/zMSzpeLM

Comment: I dont understand what you were trying to do with an AsyncTask if the init method needs to be called from the UI thread. Just create a handler in your onCreate and set a delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are starting tha `AsyncTask` in the `onCreate()`, you will still see a delay because the operations executed by the task in the `onPostExecute()` will be queued on the UI thread, which means it will be concurrent with the UI stuff.

Said this, I suggest you to simply start the `AsyncTask` with an arbitrary initial delay.

Comment: This solved the issue, although it seems to take a LOT longer before the actual player appears (15-20 seconds instead of 2-5). But at least I can display something of a loader, so the user knows we're loading.

Comment: Yes, that's the trick. You can also try to tune the initial delay to get the best experience.